# How to pass stdin inputs to a docker container and run a piece of code within the container?

Tags: docker, dockerode

I have a gcc container that compiles a piece of code and gives me the output. The code that has to be run within the container has a "cin>>" to read the input from the terminal.
I am using dockerode for the application and the code, input to the code is passed from the frontend.

```
const containerConfig = {
    Image: gcc
    Cmd: [
        "bash",
        "-c",
        `echo "${code}" > myapp.cpp && g++ -o myapp myapp.cpp && ./myapp`,
     ];
    Tty: true,
 
  };
 
const container = await docker.createContainer(containerConfig);
```

I am able to parse the output from the logs after the code is run in the container.
Is there any way so that I can pass the input to my code that is run within the container? One way of doing it is instead of using a "cin>>" I can directly append the input parameters in the string "code" used in echo. I dont think it is an efficient or correct approach.
I am trying to learn docker and any improvement over the existing method is appreciated.